# Possible log identity?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have an inequality of the form,

$$n-A\alpha\log(n) \geq A\log(B)$$

that I would like to invert to find the valid region for $n$.  The function $\log(\cdot)$ denotes the natural logarithm, $A>0$, $B>0$, and $\alpha>1$ are constants.

I thought that there might be an identity of some kind that I'm missing.

Comment: Using the power laws, you can see it is equivalent to $\dfrac{e^n}{n^\alpha}\ge Be^A$. A closed form to revert it can be given in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but for practical purposes, it is best to use numerical methods like Newton's method/fixed point iteration/etc. The closed form is given by $n\in (0,-\alpha W_0(p)]\cup [-\alpha W_{-1}(p),\infty)$ where $p=-\dfrac{(Be^A)^{-1/\alpha}}{\alpha}$ where $W_{-1},~W_0$ denote the two real branches of the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the fact that the solution to the equation $we^w=z$ is $W_k(z)$, the Lambert-W function.

$n - A\alpha \log(n) \geq A\log(B)$

We exponentiate both sides.

$e^n n^{-A\alpha} \geq B^A$

Now, we take the $-A\alpha$'th root of each side.

$\displaystyle{e^{-\frac{n}{A\alpha}}}n \geq B^{-\frac{1}{\alpha}}$

And again, multiply by $-\frac{1}{A\alpha}$, to get

$\displaystyle{-e^{-\frac{n}{A\alpha}}}\frac{n}{A\alpha} \leq -\frac{B^{-\frac{1}{a}}}{A\alpha}$.

Looking back at the first equation, we see that $w =- \frac{n}{A\alpha}$ and $z = -\frac{B^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{A\alpha}$.

So we solve to get $-\frac{n}{A\alpha} = W(-\frac{B^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{A\alpha})$, and so $n = -A\alpha W(-\frac{B^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{A\alpha})$.